# Mutex creation creates a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mutex, semaphore

I do not understand why there is a segmentation fault on creation of the following mutex:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <semaphore.h> // include POSIX semaphores
#include <fcntl.h>



struct semaphoreStruct{
  sem_t *mutex;
};




struct semaphoreStruct *semaphore_list;

int main(){

  sem_unlink("MUTEX");
  semaphore_list->mutex = sem_open("MUTEX", O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0700,1);
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't reserve space for the pointer to `struct`, leading to undefined behaviour when a value is assigned to one of his members.

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about that ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting segmentation fault because memory is not allocated for the `struct semaphoreStruct *semaphore_list` pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <semaphore.h> // include POSIX semaphores
#include <fcntl.h>

struct semaphoreStruct{
  sem_t *mutex;
};

struct semaphoreStruct *semaphore_list;

int main(){
  semaphore_list = malloc(sizeof(struct semaphoreStruct)); //allocate the memory for the struct
  sem_unlink("MUTEX");
  semaphore_list->mutex = sem_open("MUTEX", O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0700,1);
  return 0;
}
```